# Busco lugar para tener un Meetup en la Ciudad de México

Tags: discusión, meetups

Estoy planeando un meetup informal en la CDMX para abril de este año. Busco un lugar donde podamos juntarnos para tener el evento.  Se que existen empresas que prestan lugar para este tipo de cosa.

El evento sería algo pequeño (entre 10-25) personas y el espacio se requiere para poder charlar y tener algunas bebidas con comida. Si conocen un lugar donde pueda preguntar por más información, por favor avísenme.

¡Gracias!

Comment: tengo a un buen amigo y a su empresa en mente :D voy a invocarlo por correo electrónico

Comment: ¿Para cuándo Sudamérica?

Comment: @Shaz si se encuentra gente cerca de ti que quiera juntarse, avísame :)

Comment: Si es de tecnología podrías preguntar en Globant, allí yo asistí a uno del JUG de CDMX.

Comment: ¿Para cuando en Guadalajara? :DD

Comment: @Shaz Mándame un correo electrónico. jgarza@ stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Hoose ^^^^^^^^

Comment: @JuanM ¿Hay alguno pensado para España? :P

Comment: @FranciscoRomero envíame un correo ;)

Comment: Ahora te envío un correo

Comment: @JuanM Perdona por la tardanza en contestar. Te he enviado un correo al correo que había un par de comentarios arriba ;)